# How to make windows service request wait until the previous request is complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, windows-services, synchronization

I am working on a window services application and my window service will call one of the web services in certain intervals (for example 3 min). From the web service I will get data from a database and using that data I will send an email.

If I am having huge sets of rows in my db table it will take some time to send the mail. Here I have the problem: The window services send the first request and it will handle some set of records. So, while processing it by the web service, the window service sends another request to the web service before it has completed the first request. 
Due to this, the web service gets the same records from db again and again whenever it receives a new request from the windows service.

Can any one suggest me how to lock the previous request until it completes its work or some other way to handle this situation?

**Web Service call:**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) 
{ 
   timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime); 
   timer.Interval = 180000; 
   timer.AutoReset = false; 
   timer.Enabled = true; 
}
```

**Inside Method**

```
        using (MailWebService call = new MailWebService())
        {

            try
            {
                call.ServiceUrl = GetWebServiceUrl();
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

                call.CheckMailQueue();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHelper.LogWriter(ex);
            }
            finally 
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call the web-service? But basically you need to wait in the windows service for the first request to complete, before sending another one...

Comment: protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = 180000;
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
i am calling web service using timer time interval

Comment: Can you edit that (and `OnElapsedTime`) to your question using code formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class works great for this scenario. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
// This is the object that we lock to control access
private static object _intervalSync = new object();

private void OnElapsedTime(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{       

    if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_intervalSync))
    {
        try
        {
            // Your code here
        }
        finally
        {
            // Make sure Exit is always called
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_intervalSync);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Previous interval is still in progress.
    }
}
```

There is also an overload for `TryEnter` that allows you to specify timeout for entering the section.

Comment: This answer worked, I just don't understand about the else statement, but anyway I put it in my code, thanks!

Comment: @VictorHD the else statement handles the case where the previous interval is still running. For example, say the timer is firing at 1 minute intervals executing your code, but every now and then you code takes longer than 1 minute to complete. In this case the Monitor can not be entered so the else statement will be evaluated. If you dont need to handle this case, you can omit the else statement.

Comment: Hey @Mike, thanks a lot for the explanation, today I followed exactly it, I'm using the service to control a process queue that will be fired over the network until now it's working perfectly at my customer.